# How to decrement a bitstring?

Tags: c++, boost, bit-manipulation, boost-dynamic-bitset

I want to have a decrement operator for a bitstring.  I currently have an incremement operator defined as follows:

```
void increment(boost::dynamic_bitset<> &bitset)
{   
    for (int loop = 0; loop < bitset.size(); ++loop)
    {
        if ((bitset[loop] ^= 0x1) == 0x1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How would I decrement in a bitstring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this would work.

```
void decrement(boost::dynamic_bitset<> &bitset) 
{    
    for (int loop = 0; loop < bitset.size(); ++loop) 
    { 
        if ((bitset[loop] ^= 0x1) == 0x0) 
        { 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That was my intuition, was just hoping for a confirmation. Thanks!